# How do I get SAS to return a value if SQL stored procedure ran properly?

Tags: sql-server, sas

I want to rerun a stored procedure with a pass-thru.  How do I get it to return a value if it runs properly or fails?

Right now, my code is returning nothing regardless of whether the stored properly is running without errors or not.

```
proc sql;
connect to odbc(noprompt="Driver={DataDirect 6.1 SQL Server Wire Protocol};Host=99.999.999.99;Port=9999;Database=ReportServer02;Uid=&userid.;Pwd=&password.;");
     create table blob as select * FROM CONNECTION TO odbc 
    (declare @r int
    exec dbo.DivByZero;
    select @r as DivByZero;);

disconnect from odbc;
```

run;

Answer (score 1):

If you return something properly (as @mallan1121 describes), then you should be able to do it with less code, actually:

```
create table blob as select * FROM CONNECTION TO odbc 
    (
    exec dbo.DivByZero;
    );
```

The RC should be automatically selected into `blob`.

You can also look at the `&SQLXRC` and `&SQLXMSG` macro variables after the SP has run (even if you use `execute ...` instead of `select from`); those ought to have the return code and any returned message in them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a return code with `RETURN()` within your stored procedure. For example:

```
IF @divisor = 0
BEGIN
 RETURN(1) --Error!
END

ELSE
BEGIN
 --do some work
 RETURN(0) --Success!
END
```

And then when you call just get the return code.

```
DECLARE @rc int
EXEC @rc = dbo.DivByZero
SELECT @rc
```

MSDN Article on SPROC return codes: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190778(v=sql.105).aspx